# c# windows phone 8.1 "use of windows namespace is reserved" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing **windows phone 8.1** app. I have create **Pivot App(Windows Phone)** from templates. In same solution I have added **Class Library(Portable for iOS, Android And windows)**. I have added class library **.dll** to windows phone project. Here is Class Library project property screenshot

[image]

After adding reference to phone project it is giving error

> The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlText'. The use of the Windows namespace is reserved.
>
> The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type
>   'Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting.ICurrencyFormatterFactory'.
>   The use of the Windows namespace is reserved.

Here is screenshot

[image]

After removing this all things working perfectly. I am not getting, why it is giving all these errors after adding `.dll`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with his references. What I did was reinstall the Windows 8 SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx

or

I do not have a machine which is upgrade from Windows 7 to Wndows 8 to test against, but in my opinion it should be the root cause of your current issue. And would you mind to correct your issue by reinstalling a clean Windows 8?

Also

It seem like you are using an older version of the sdk.

Comment: Try creating a new project with nothing in it add the dll and build the solution see if that work an let me know

Comment: In windows phone project I have only `two xaml page` and `Json dll`.

Comment: Make sure that the dll traget framwork is the same as your project

Comment: Yes, you can see it in image. But still there is issue.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have you application or a class named windows or a variable etc

Comment: Yes. I don't have any such names.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar list of error in my Windows Phone 8.1 project, and it turned out that I was referencing Windows.winmd (Shown as 'Windows' under references) from one of the PCL projects in my solution! When I removed that reference, errors disappeared.